# Offset Right and Bottom in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, positioning, offset

The following code is a sample from w3schools.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var x = $("p").offset();
        alert("Top: " + x.top + " Left: " + x.left);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Return the offset coordinates of the p element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

it is possible to get offset right and offset bottom using jquery?

Link :

https://jsfiddle.net/0hhxdbk5/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var right = ($(window).width() - ($element.offset().left + $element.outerWidth()));

var bottom = $(window).height() - top - link.height();
```

This should do it.

Comment: Sorry, link would be : var link = $(element);

Comment: Thank You and top means offset top?